# Notificações por Push

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, push-notification

Estou desenvolvendo um programa em que vários usuários irão utilizar, e gostaria de desenvolver um sistema com notificação `Push`, para quando algum usuário realizar um `Insert` no banco de dados.

Gostaria que fosse, como por exemplo, um `pop-up` do MSN..

Alguém poderia me dar um luz e me dizer por onde devo começar?
Andei pesquisando, achei bastante coisa sobre `Web`, mas não especificamente para `Windows Forms`(`WFA`).

- Revisão 11/04/2017

Como faria para quando um usuário finalizar alguma alteração, outro usuário receba a notificação?

Teria que ter um `serviço` rodando no servidor?

Em pesquisa pela internet, notei, que o `SQL Server`, dispõe de alguns recursos:

1. [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx);
2. [Query Notification](http://dominatudo.blogspot.com.br/2012/09/query-notification-sql-server.html).

Alguém já tentou utilizar ou já usou? Será esse um recurso para tal finalidade?

Answer (score 1):

Utilizo no meu sistema o componente [*Balloon*](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/features.aspx) do DevComponents

[image: BalloonTip]

para setar o local de exibição eu seto a seguite configuração do balão

```
b.DesktopLocation = new Point(SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Width - b.Width, SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Height - b.Height);
```

Mas você também pode optar por desenvolver seu próprio 'Balão de Informações' Criando um form com parâmetros para a imagem e texto desejado setando sua localização da mesma forma do exemplo acima

```
new Point(SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Width - b.Width, SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Height - b.Height);
```

Caso resolva utilizar o *Balloon* seguem as configurações a serem setadas no código para ele ser exibido como na imagem

```
balloonTipFocus.Enabled = true;

            Balloon b = new Balloon();

            b.CreateControl();
            //     DevComponents.DotNetBar.Balloon b = new DevComponents.DotNetBar.Balloon();
            b.AlertAnimation = eAlertAnimation.BottomToTop;
            b.Style = eBallonStyle.Office2007Alert;
            b.CaptionImage = IMAGEM;//Imagem exibida no balão
            b.CaptionText = "Texto Titulo";
            b.Text = "Texto corpo da mensagem";
            b.AutoResize();//Auto Ajusta tamanho do Balão ao Texto
            b.AutoClose = true;
            b.AutoCloseTimeOut = 5;//Tempo para o componente fechar automaticamente
            b.Owner = this;
            b.AntiAlias = true;
            b.AlertAnimationDuration = 200;
            b.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right);
            b.DesktopLocation = new Point(SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Width - b.Width, SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Height - b.Height);

            b.Show();
```

Comment: amigo, perfeito, obrigado pela resposta, mas, como faria para quando um usuario salvar alguma alteração, um outro usuario receber a notificação? teria que ter um serviço rodando no servidor?

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel Acredito que seria necessário um serviço para tal, se existe outra forma desconheço(visto que nunca utilizei tal função) mas não sei qual seria a melhor forma de implementar isto sem perder tanta performance